# I am having an undefined error when trying to call a method in a different class

Tags: java, methods

I have 2 classes written in java here they are

```
public class MinHeapify{
public MinHeapify(String a[], int start, int end){
minHeapify(a,start,end);
}
public static void exchange(String a[],int i,int j) {
String temp = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = temp;
}
public static int parent(int i) {
return (int) Math.floor((i - 1)/2);
}
public static int left(int i) {
return 2*i + 1;
}
public static int right(int i) {
return 2*(i+1);
}
public static void minHeapify(String a[], int start,int end) {
int l = left(start); int r = right(start);
int smallest=0;
if(l >= end){
  smallest = (l < start)? l: start;
}
if(r >= end){
  smallest = (r < smallest)? r: smallest;
}
if(smallest != start) {
  exchange(a,start,smallest);
  minHeapify(a,smallest,end);
}
}
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReservationArray{
private String [] array = new String [50];

public ReservationArray(String [] arg){
int next = 0;
int next2 = 0;
while(arg[++next]!= null){
  if(next != arg.length){
    arg[next] = array[next2];
    next = next++;
    next2 = next2++;
  }
  else if(next == array.length && next!= arg.length){
    String [] temp = new String[2*array.length+1];
    for(int i=0; i<next; i++){
      temp[i] = array[i];
      array = temp;
      temp = null;
    }
  } else{
    if(next < (array.length/2)-1){
      String [] temp = new String[1/2*array.length-1];
    for(int i=0; i<next; i++){
      temp[i] = array[i];
      array = temp;
      temp = null;
    }
    }
  }
}
minHeapify(array, 0, array.length-1);

}
```

The error that I get when i try and compile it is " The method minHeapify(java.lang.String[], int, int) is undefined for the type ReservationArray" and I do not understand what that means, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
MinHeapify mh = new MinHeapify();
mh.minHeapify(array, 0, array.length-1);
```

Since your method is static, you should call this way.

```
MinHeapify.(array, 0, array.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `minHeapify` belongs to the `MinHeapify`class rather than `ReservationArray`, hence the error. As its `static`, you can use:

```
MinHeapify.minHeapify(array, 0, array.length - 1);
```

Alternatively, you could use a `static` import:

```
import static com.your.package.MinHeapify.minHeapify;
```

And use the current unqualified method call notation.

Answer (score 1):

add the return type to it

```
public void MinHeapify(String a[], int start, int end)
```

and

```
MinHeapify.minHeapify(array, 0, array.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well minHeapify is a method is the class MinHeapify. You can't access it in the class ReservationArray unless you use the reference to MinHeapify to access it.